# Confusion related to bayesian spatial scan statistics

Tags: bayesian, spatial

I was reading this paper related to bayesian spatial scan statistics. http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips18/NIPS2005_0513.pdf. It's said that when we use bayesian spatial scan statistics, we don't need to use the randomization testing or significance testing of the found potential cluster. Why is it so? I didn't get it. Any insights on this?

Comment: In Section 1.1 the authors describe the frequentist scan statistic, they explain there how "randomization testing is used to compute the *p*-value of each detected region". In Section 2 the authors describe the Bayesian scan statistic, and *note* that, by construction, "no randomization testing is necessary", which has implications on the complexity of the algorithm. They mention a particular case in which the complexity (total computation time) is reduced from $O(RN^4)$ for $R=1000$ to $O(N^4)$.